# mysql select and MAX()

Tags: mysql, max

I am going nuts already, don't know what else to try.
I got this data:

Table name is `erste`

```
valuta  kupovni    
EUR     7.435   
GBP     9.2132
```

And then I try this:

```
SELECT valuta, MAX(kupovni)
FROM erste
```

I get this:

```
valuta  MAX(kupovni)
 EUR    9.213199615478516
```

And I want to get:

```
GBP 9.2132
```

Column valuta is `varchar(3)` and `kupovni` is `float (10)`.
I really dont know what I am doing it wrong.
When I try:

```
SELECT valuta, MAX(kupovni)
FROM erste
GROUP BY kupovni
```

It does it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This merely seems like a simple matter of selecting the row with the highest value for the `kupovni` field.

You can do:

```
SELECT valuta, kupovni
FROM erste
ORDER BY kupovni DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Struna, please reread the question more carefully and look closer. The OP simply wants the row with the max `kupovni`. Even if there are rows with the same max `kupovni`, the OP only wants one row returned. The order of the data in the table does not matter since the query orders by `kupovni` regardless of how the rows were inserted. Bohemian's solution just gets the max `kupovni` where `valuta` is GBP. The OP wants the highest row in the table regardless of the `valuta`. Also in Bohemian's solution, if you've got `WHERE valuta = 'GBP'`, then his `GROUP BY` is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Struna, oh okay, no problem!

Comment: BTW, I am now to mysql, so I failed to realize that you can use aggregate functions only with "order by". They are even called GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions lol. Well, lesson learned...

Comment: I know this is an old question, but to @user1511031 question on why the query was acting as it was, the answer comes in two parts: 1st- for why he was getting 9.213199615478516 instead of the desired 9.2132, check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html. 2nd- on why he was getting EUR instead of GBP is because the of the use of a select with an aggregation function (MAX) without a GROUP BY CLAUSE, so the column value for the first row was being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close! Here's what you need:

```
SELECT valuta, MAX(kupovni)
FROM erste
where valuta = 'GBP' -- optional where clause
group by valuta
```

You must "group by" all columns not aggregated by an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Unless you really *need* the `valuta` in the output, because you know `valuta`, I would do this:

```
SELECT MAX(kupovni)
FROM erste
where valuta = 'GBP'
```

(Note that mysql allows columns to be omitted from the group by, in which case you'll get the only the *first* row encountered for each group)

Comment: Could you please explain this "You must "group by" all columns not aggregated by an aggregate function."?

I said in my post I tried this, but I want just one value as result, as I described. I want whole row where max function got match.

Comment: you need to tell mysql what columns form the "group" you are finding the "max" for. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT valuta, TRUNCATE(MAX(kupovni),4)
FROM erste
group by valuta
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT erste.* 
  FROM ( SELECT valuta, MAX(kupovni) AS maxtotal
           FROM erste
           GROUP BY valuta) AS dt
INNER JOIN erste
    ON erste.valuta= dt.valuta
   AND erste.kupovni= dt.maxtotal 
ORDER BY items_purchased.val DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I want just one row as result to my quiery

Comment: How about adding in ORDER BY and LIMIT 1?